# Why does Lord Vishnu create water by penance, and then retire to sleep before beginning world drama every time before the creation of universe,

Tags: vishnu, shiva, time

Every time before creating universe, why Lord Vishnu creates water by penance devoted to Lord Shiva and sleep before beginning world drama?

Is it like he see everything in advance and make it static or planned?

If the universe had a beginning, why did it wait an infinite time before it began?

Comment: According to Shiva Purana, water emerges from body of Lord Vishnu when He does tapasya, during beginning of creation. In that water, Brahmanda floats. Later, Vishnu enters the Brahmanda and makes it sentient. Yes, this is all destined. But "why" water comes is difficult to say.